# Android, java, view.setOnTouchListener

Tags: java, android

Был у меня recyclerview с адаптером и все было круто. Я добавил view.setOnTouchListener чтобы я мог скроллить этот recyclerview вместе с анимацией и другими элементами на 1 экране слева направо. Но после этого в recyclerview сломался скроллинг вверх-вниз, а так же onclicklistener на элементах внутри перестал работать. Что делать и как пофиксить этот конфликт?
На дайнный момент я могу в методе public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) поставить return false; вместо return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event); и получить рабочий скроллинг вверх-вниз обратно, но влево-вправо перестает работать.
Я же могу сделать одновременный скроллинг как в ios, когда при добавлении свайпа влево-вправо не ломались скроллинги тейблвиевов и коллекций?

Сори, я тут в 1 раз пробую спрашивать, обычно до этого загуглить все получалось:

```
       public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        view.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MainActivity.this) {
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                choseold = chosenow;
                chosenow = chosenow - 1;
                if (chosenow <= 0) {
                    chosenow = 5;
                    choseold = 6;
                }
                swipe();
            }
            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                choseold = chosenow;
                chosenow = chosenow + 1;
                if (chosenow >= 6) {
                    chosenow = 1;
                    choseold = 0;
                }
                swipe();
            }

        });
        view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);


        MyAdapterlang = new MyAdapterLang(MainActivity.this, yaziki1, yaziki2, flagi);
        RVlang.setAdapter(MyAdapterlang);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        RV1.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        MyAdapter = new MyAdapterApps(MainActivity.this, childs, childs2);
        RV1.setAdapter(MyAdapter);
    }
}

    class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

        private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

        public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            //return false;
        }
        /*public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    y1 = event.getY();

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    y2 = event.getY();

                    float deltaY = y2 - y1;

                    if (Math.abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                    }
            }

            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        private float y1, y2;
        private static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 50;*/

        private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

            private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
            private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                try {
                    float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                    float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                        if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                            if (diffX > 0) {
                                onSwipeRight();
                            } else {
                                onSwipeLeft();
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void onSwipeRight() {
        }

        public void onSwipeLeft() {
        }
    }
```

Вот в ios, например, очень просто и не ломает скроллинг коллекций:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeleft=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeleft:)];
    swipeleft.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeleft];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swiperight=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swiperight:)];
    swiperight.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swiperight];
}

-(void)swipeleft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (self.currentnew <= 3) {
        self.whatpress = 1;
        [self.buttonnew sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
}

-(void)swiperight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
    if ((self.currentnew >= 1) && (self.currentnew <= 3)) {
        self.whatpress = 2;
        [self.buttonnew sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
}
```

Вот видео еще:
https://2ch.hk/pr/src/1314926/15464190246250.mp4
https://2ch.hk/pr/src/1314926/15464193253190.mp4

Comment: Свой код вы принципиально не хотите показывать? Не ждите телепатов -- проиллюстрируйте свой вопрос примером кода.

Comment: Насколько мне известно как в iOS сделать - очень сложно. За несколько лет на этом сайте видел несколько попыток - ни у кого не получилось.

Comment: Пару лет назад видел на сайте devlight.io представленное подобное решение , точно не помню название, но у них куча библиотек в этом направлении, надеюсь чем-то помог

Comment: Можно попробовать в recycler класть horizontal scroll. Или переписать кастомный обработчик чтобы он только на горизонтальное перемещение работал. Но может быть много перерисовок.